# Problem with Joomla Template

Tags: joomla

I have installed Joomla 1.5.4 and the Hybrid template from RocketTheme. It was successful, however the front page doesn't look like its supposed to. I am new to Joomla so I am not sure what I am supposed to do to use the Templates front page, it seems like its using the old version still.

Here are some screenshots.

http://completecare.linuxd.org/ss1.jpg

http://completecare.linuxd.org/ss2.jpg

It is supposed to look like:
http://demo.rockettheme.com/?template=hybrid

But only the top of the page changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Module Manager** >and Enable the Modules which came with the theme or if they are not these install them and enable them !.. This theme use some custom Modules

[image]

[image]